# Construct new forward_list from iterators into existing forward_list via node splicing

Tags: c++, performance, iterator, c++17, forward-list

If you have a `std::list`, and want to rebuild it into a new `std::list` in a different order, without copying, from iterators into the original `std::list`, it's fairly straightforward, for example, if you're shuffling the iterators and rebuilding from the shuffled order:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::list<std::string> args(&argv[1], &argv[argc]);
    std::vector<std::list<std::string>::const_iterator> vec;
    for (auto it = std::cbegin(args), last = std::cend(args); it != last; ++it) {
        vec.push_back(it);
    }

    std::shuffle(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::mt19937(42));  // Shuffle with reproducible PRNG

    std::cout << "Shuffled vec:\n";
    for (auto it : vec) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    std::list<std::string> shuffled_args;
    for (auto it : vec) {
        shuffled_args.splice(std::end(shuffled_args), args, it);
    }

    std::cout << "Shuffled list:\n";
    for (const auto& s : shuffled_args) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works great; on my system, when compiled with `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -flto -Wall shuffle_list.cpp` and run with `./a.out a b c d e`, the results from printing both the `vector` and the shuffled `list` agree (`e a c d b` in that order): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVI7T8MwEN7zKw6QUNI2QAEJNU27sgGCgQFQ5TpOauHake3AgPjrGF9c1IQWiSz2Pb7HnUPrOq0odUdcUtEUDHIiKqW5Xa3n0TbJlbGakV5OcGO7sSayUL0Oj@Gy6mbeGLVKzx2XFtaEyxgvRFd0BHRFNAwGPnhLoo8I/GdskWUok7e3DR32m/gYG5/GLyMINyR5SaZbXJDK93NkGVXS2AW3TBN0BL49gEulISaNVcAtzAIXXbLKm0XhZASCmG2FySLkp9h/MGurUxgOuU0gjIGfpz@pG7NaLAl9jX0tiH1GW8Nm1ZSlYHEbBEGP8nptAnU64dqOJ5OLq/jyPPHKcHoKDwEO7/7tQLNaq6KhfOkzd/c31x0dqhoLeQ6HG0SB5rJnebhn/gxr3Tl6DAPeHj/@xO5Mu4@3mbJY4NL@pdgFnJhacLrZEa6kV/XLwWMEe/e7Oze6@zV4@1sAmjkG4830@f9ahPl7DZrZRks4m0afzjnilo66wrEvWgpSGZd61IwOh@Mrl95euLQUVrn0kQjxDQ)

But when I try to write a variant version using `std::forward_list`, things get dicier. This is the only version that doesn't segfault (with comments indicating changes):

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::forward_list<std::string> args(&argv[1], &argv[argc]);
    std::vector<std::forward_list<std::string>::const_iterator> vec;
    for (auto it = args.cbefore_begin(), last = std::cend(args); std::next(it) != last; ++it) { // Changed to store iterators before each element since splice_after needs them
        vec.push_back(it);
    }

    std::shuffle(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::mt19937(42));

    std::cout << "Shuffled vec:\n";
    for (auto it : vec) {
        std::cout << *std::next(it) << std::endl;  // Must advance each iterator to see value stored
    }

    std::forward_list<std::string> shuffled_args;
    auto splice_loc = shuffled_args.cbefore_begin();      // Must begin inserting at beginning of new forward_list
    for (auto it : vec) {
        shuffled_args.splice_after(splice_loc, args, it); // splice_loc is before when node should go, it points to node before node to splice, great
        splice_loc = it;                                  // it should now be last element, it will be next splice location
    }

    std::cout << "Shuffled list:\n";
    for (const auto& s : shuffled_args) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output here is the same from the `vector`, but for the resulting `forward_list` it just outputs `e`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNbxMxEL3nVwxFqjZfLaVIVZO0Fw6c@BAcOEAVOfbsroVjR7Y3Qar61zFje9PsNhTYk/3smffmzXj5ZjOtOA8vpeaqEQgLpipjpa/Xt4MDKI3zFlkPK43dMSuWSjrfxS3TwvRuUqzUVRfZIvfG3gapPayZ1EVcMFvxCfCaWRiNaLMdDu4HQJ/zYjbr0i0S0qaNca44jQHfLu4mkFcx2d1wfojPlIu/55rNuNHOL6VHy6JCoLCchGKgYI03ID3cJNIzvkKCcbnCimoYTkAxFw9TSo5aFPHacJ4BjT99If0QXtyki3MYj@P2Hs7P4W3NdIUCKL8jYoS9BAeZBJDxGlDhGskrR1YiuI2SHJespLugEYUDX@M66Y0fiT/bNK5erhj/EalzKQ@Dgy2ubspSYZE2uQ6KolISEEvobNf@4vr68qp483pIRUXZX3I47GhiwOLGGtFwuSLk0@cP7zo83DQeFgs4aSNEFDf7rk/@4O4snpEvj3X0Moz6ZhKyl6qypvcNNYGJLYsWJdf2XiZ3EWHLVIPZZ3HkyPOD1nollrGrWXeS3LZBGR573730dELmuZ69yISC1A6tJwZgLaTjxpTU0h105fyPVT367oAUB5mTNL4TiBMRxXQKkI/ztqtRgzb0XF1tGiWgMjECNoYeq4tWpsP2dlo/ejGBin4X/qCq65D0c/jnR6qIq2XWZkc8@XW1LyBJ2Uml4kEchpYDiIN5afRRX48nMFr6ZATT809dPQVH7vbsfHYkXX8Ku9QWfWM1vJoPHkIILKwCDyLgL14qVrkwpagbPh5fXIXpx8swLZU3YfqVKfUb) If you try other fun things like replacing `splice_loc = it;` with `++splice_loc;` (which is logically equivalent; you spliced in a node after the current location, and advancing the iterator should move you to that new node), it segfaults.

**I think I know why this is broken (it's two different ways for the full code and the replacement with `++splice_loc`), and I don't think the approach I'm taking is salvageable**. In the segfaulting code, as I splice nodes over, the iterators remain valid, but some of the iterators in the original structure are moved before I get to them (e.g. I use position 1's iterator to move the item at 2, and when I try to move 3 via 2, it moves some other random thing that follows 2 in the new list), and now I'm trying to splice in what follows them in the new `forward_list` (and violating the API, as I claim they came from `args`, when they've in fact been moved to `shuffled_args` at that point). There's no good fix for this in the design I've chosen AFAICT.  **Update:** In the non-segfaulting code, I should be saving off `std::next(it)` before the splice and assigning that to `splice_loc` (by assigning `it`, which is probably still in the original `forward_list`, the `splice_loc` now points to the original list and I'm probably engaging in undefined behavior that ultimately modifies the original list more than the new one).

My question is:

**Is there a *good* way to do what I want, taking iterators from a `forward_list`, jumbling them up (with `shuffle` or sorting or whatever), then building a new `forward_list` in an alternate order, by direct node transfer (no copies or moves of *any* of the contained elements), and doing so efficiently?** The best I can come up with is making a new dedicated `forward_list` for *each* node in the `vector`, so I can splice that single node over to the final `forward_list`. This feels ugly, and possibly more expensive than the `list` equivalent behavior. Is there a better way? Is the many one-element `forward_list` solution actually great?

---

For the curious: This is a stripped down reproducer of a problem I'm having writing a keyed sorting algorithm (as in Schwartzian transform aka decorate-sort-undecorate), entirely as a personal challenge. I'm trying to make a specialized version for `std::list` and `std::forward_list` that avoids any copies or moves of the values being sorted by decorating the iterators rather than the values themselves, so once I've sorted the collection by the computed keys, I can then construct a new `list` or `forward_list` by using `splice`/`splice_after` to rebuild the container in the sorted order, without copying or moving a single one of the contained values.

Comment: In the second program, why do you start from the "before beginning" iterator? You know it can't be dereferenced? It's a very big difference from the first program where you start with the normal "beginning" iterator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It's a requirement for how `splice_after` works; `splice_after` puts the spliced node after the iterator provided (so to insert the first node, you need to use the before beginning iterator) and it extracts the node to splice from the iterator pointing to the node before it. It complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working version based on my original suggestion to use a bunch of single node `std::forward_list`s. It *feels* inefficient to make all this `std::forward_list`s, but from what I can tell, `std::forward_list` is spec-ed so narrowly that it's almost guaranteed to be implemented as a wrapper around a single pointer, which should be pretty low overhead. And it does work, with no copies or moves of the contained elements, nor (thanks to the use of `deque`) any copies or moves of the `forward_list`s themselves (aside from when we empty them to splice them onto the output `forward_list`), and it only traverses the input `forward_list` once (destroying it by extracting the first node over and over until it's emptied).

It's not the prettiest, but it's not nearly as ugly or inefficient as I was expecting.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::forward_list<std::string> args(&argv[1], &argv[argc]);
    std::deque<std::forward_list<std::string>> deq;  // Use deque so we never have to move existing forward_lists, and don't need to pre-walk to find size to reserve for vector
    while (!args.empty()) {
        auto& flist = deq.emplace_back();
        flist.splice_after(flist.cbefore_begin(), args, args.cbefore_begin());  // Extract a single node from input to populate new forward_list
    }

    std::shuffle(std::begin(deq), std::end(deq), std::mt19937(42));  // Shuffle with reproducible PRNG

    std::cout << "Shuffled deq:\n";
    for (auto& flist : deq) {
        std::cout << flist.front() << std::endl;
    }

    std::forward_list<std::string> shuffled_args;
    auto splice_loc = shuffled_args.cbefore_begin();
    for (auto&& flist : deq) {
        shuffled_args.splice_after(splice_loc, std::move(flist));  // splice single element forward_list contents onto end
        ++splice_loc;  // We added one element, move the iterator forward by one
    }

    std::cout << "Shuffled list:\n";
    for (const auto& s : shuffled_args) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVNRb9MwEH7vrziGNJK13ShDmtZ2e0O8AQKhPcA0ufYltebYwXbaDbS/jjnH7Zp0Kn5I4vN9d999n8PrelxyHl5LzVUjEOZMlcZKv6yuB7ugwF8NdgPSOG@R9ZIKY9fMijslne/GLdPC9DIJK3V5HaT2UDGps/jBbMlHwJfMwskJbVb54M8AaDkvptNu8Xkb2RSJOJcdR8CPye0I0lcsdpvPdvh2gvn/S10DZc0Azs7gu0NoIeAMrBE0rtDCkq0QvIHK0BsfCE8w6NZzI6BpQRj9xhMIRUyvLY7XTN3H70LSsZO/2zoWHVoqRRVghdwb2xJeL6VCyF7FyU6xqv1jlueQxIiLNd4cQxH7wVWkGZMU43i3YPw@24wdV5tz6mol6ZAVHm2WQnyB1JQAWJL8@ahVMT33z/KkyIcHbxknm4i9LomfNmRlYU0FUteNbwc1daOYj3Kte7K0hJ4GOzvcsikKhVm7SY1oDuLRBlCL7rbyk8vL84vs/bstmW8JDmu6qKRibY1ouFxQ5MvXTx87fbghZvM5HG0QIso1/amPkkZR@Kwr5zSed7XuVUna0czaZ3kMbNmq2YsJD1/YzeziLqqdgJECbGxShpOrvaR9S/bJH2bfq9K7B7tuW5XpUqfbsVU5pWz9RoUV0n/aHQw4SUFBB/Q2QEo8tx4Odx1SuRsEJgRZYPRztVH6l/wSQRIrRr/AtgEsHmPmC2FfWhqZ7HlKvIhdctaRLj0hDvrrDntq0TdWw9vZ4CmEwMIi8CAC/uWFYqULY0Jd8eFwchHGn8/DuFDehPENU@of)

To be clear, if anyone has any better solutions, I'm happy to hear about them and would love to give the checkmark to something cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not compatible with the concept of a singly-linked list (which is what `forward_list` is). Your algorithm, at its core, requires being able to use an iterator into a list as sufficient information to extract that node from the list.

To remove a node from such a list, you need to get the previous node and change its "next" pointer to point to the to-be-removed node's "next" pointer. You cannot get the previous node just from a particular node in a singly-linked list.

If you jumble up a bunch of pointers to nodes of a singly-linked list (which is what `forward_list::iterator`s are), there is no way to get the previous node in order to extract that node.

The only thing you could do is to extract all of the nodes into individual `forward_list`s containing exactly one element, jumble them up, and splice those single-element lists into the final list. But even this requires care, as `splice_after` does not return an iterator. So you'll need to get the iterator from the single-element list before the splice, splice it in, and then use that as the `pos` for the next splice. The very first one shouldn't be a splice; it should instead be a move.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the reason why one of my solutions segfaulted while the other just dropped data (and edited that into the question; it has no impact on your answer). I also just posted an answer with the single-element `forward_list`s; it wasn't quite as bad as I was expecting (using `splice_after` was pretty easy there actually; I just splice in the whole single-element `forward_list`, then increment the `splice_loc`; by definition advancing it one element will advance it to the single node I just inserted). I didn't bother with the `move` since the effect is the same either way.

Comment: It seems like the concept could be done trivially with a singly-linked list, just not a `std::forward_list`.  It's true we need to set the previous node's next pointer to properly reorder the list, and we don't have that from a pointer to the to-be-removed node.  But we do have a pointer to the previous node!  We know a pointer to *every node* is in the vector of shuffled pointers somewhere.  If we process the entire vector of iterators, we can assured that we will have set every "previous node's" next pointer correctly.  We just didn't do it in order.